# Is an interface class needed in factory method?

Tags: python, class, oop, factory-pattern

Recently I realized that a factory method can be implemented in Python without the need of an intermediate interface class. Then, your products directly inherit from the factory class.

The only issue I see is that when using an interface class, if defined as abstract, an instance cannot be created. Is this the only reason to justify the creation of a interface class?

Herebelow, I have pasted two examples which reproduce exactly the same output.

What I consider... not perfect:

```
class PersonFactory():
    def create_person(self, name):
        if name == 'John':
            return John()
        elif name == 'Peter':
            return Peter()
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError

    def eat(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def sleep(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class John(PersonFactory):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = 'John'

    def eat(self):
        print(f'[{self.name}] I am eating pizza')

    def sleep(self):
        print(f'[{self.name}] I sleep 8.15h a day')


class Peter(PersonFactory):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = 'Peter'

    def eat(self):
        print(f'[{self.name}] I am eating meat')

    def sleep(self):
        print(f'[{self.name}] I sleep 7h a day')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    first_person = PersonFactory().create_person('John')
    first_person.eat()
    first_person.sleep()

    second_person = PersonFactory().create_person('Peter')
    second_person.eat()
    second_person.sleep()
```

What I consider correct:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class PersonFactory():
    def create_person(self, name):
        if name == 'John':
            return John()
        elif name == 'Peter':
            return Peter()
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError


class IPerson(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def eat(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abstractmethod
    def sleep(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class John(IPerson):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = 'John'

    def eat(self):
        print(f'[{self.name}] I am eating pizza')

    def sleep(self):
        print(f'[{self.name}] I sleep 8.15h a day')


class Peter(IPerson):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = 'Peter'

    def eat(self):
        print(f'[{self.name}] I am eating meat')

    def sleep(self):
        print(f'[{self.name}] I sleep 7h a day')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    first_person = PersonFactory().create_person('John')
    first_person.eat()
    first_person.sleep()

    second_person = PersonFactory().create_person('Peter')
    second_person.eat()
    second_person.sleep()
```

Comment: There is no need for `IPerson` at all, although, it may serve as good way to be explicit about what is expected. But this is often just omitted in Python. And really, your factory can just be a function. Python generally has much less cruft than Java, because due to it's very dynamic nature, it simply isn't *necessary*

Comment: `class Peter(PersonFactory):` that *definitely* doesn't make sense, your classes shouldn't inherit from the factory...

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of modeling your domain as classes, does it make sense for John or Peter (or any Person) to have the method `create_person()`? Maybe, but should a `PersonFactory` have methods `eat()` and `sleep()`?

Beyond this, the implementation above is somewhat problematic in that it mixes differing information (state) with differing behavior (implementation) and overall isn't particularly Pythonic -- which isn't in and of itself bad, but it's helpful to stay within the idioms of the language. Consider something like this, which actually avoids the need for an `abc.ABC` by providing a base class with a couple of concrete methods that can be inherited:

```
def create_person(name):
    # ... implement the factory as a function. It's a domain service.
    pass

class PersonBase:
    name: str = None
    sleep_duration: str = None
    food: str = None
        
    def eat(self):
        print(f'[{self.name}] I am eating {self.food}')

    def sleep(self):
        print(f'[{self.name}] I sleep {self.sleep_duration} a day')

class John(PersonBase):
    name = "John"
    sleep_duration = "8.15h"
    food = "pizza"

class Peter(PersonBase):
    name = "Peter"
    sleep_duration = "7h"
    food = "meat"
```